# Can sed be made recursive in for windows?

Tags: windows, recursion, sed, directory

I'm using [sed for windows](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/sed.htm) to do search and replace on some javascript files, and I was wondering if using some other utility I could make it work recursively.

Comment: Seems like find utilities might do the trick...(http://broadcast.oreilly.com/2009/08/recursively-edit-files-with-se.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

yes you can, either use a `for` loop coupled with `dir /s`, or you can use [find for windows](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/findutils.htm). eg

```
find c:\path -iname "*.txt" -exec sed "s/old/new/g" "{}" ;
```

Comment: Yeah that did the trick (except for the -iname argument doesn't work) you have to type it more like:

find . "*.js" -exec sed -i "s/old/new/g" ;